# bat file to run perl script on all sub directories

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have a simple bat file that sets a directory and runs a perl on the directory.

```
cd Q:\Research\Images(new)\MuseumSpecimens\DBG\DBG_Specimens\DBG_ToBeRenamed
perl Q:\Research\Images(new)\MuseumSpecimens\DBG\DBG_Specimens\zbar\barcode.pl
```

I want to modify the bat file so that it runs the perl script on each sub directory within the directory (each folder within DBG_ToBe_Renamed) in this case. So far I have the following, but it isn't quite right.

```
FOR /R Q:\Research\Images(new)\MuseumSpecimens\DBG\DBG_Specimens\test\ %%G IN (.) DO perl Q:\Research\Images(new)\MuseumSpecimens\DBG\DBG_Specimens\zbar\barcode.pl
```

Thanks, I appreciate any help.

If it helps, the perl script reads barcodes from JPEGs and creates new files with the JPEG and associated RAW file renamed using the barcode value (https://github.com/psweeney-YU/reBar/blob/master/reBar.pl)

Comment: If you have a choice, do the dir search in perl? batch file directory tracking is a pain!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for /D %%d in (Q:\Research\Images(new)\MuseumSpecimens\DBG\DBG_Specimens\DBG_ToBeRenamed\*) do pushd %%d && perl Q:\Research\Images(new)\MuseumSpecimens\DBG\DBG_Specimens\zbar\barcode.pl && popd
```

Comment: The above is very dependent upon no characters like for example spaces and ampersands...

Comment: Take it, in this context, to mean the opposite of some characters.